# Symfony 2: calling an undefined method

Tags: php, symfony

I am using the FOS Message Bundle, but it looks like it doesn't recognize the following method:

```
$threads = $this->getProvider()->getInboxThreads();
```

I get this errormessage:

```
Attempted to call an undefined method named "getProvider" of class "AppBundle\Controller\MessageController"
```

Here is the code for the controller:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use FOS\MessageBundle\Provider\ProviderInterface;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

class MessageController extends ContainerAware
{
    /**
     * @Route("/messages/", name="messages_home")
     */
    public function inboxAction()
    {
        $threads = $this->getProvider()->getInboxThreads();

        return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('inbox/inbox.html.twig', array(
            'threads' => $threads
        ));
    }
}
```

I suspected it had something to do with my usings, but I changed it and that didn't seem to help me...

Answer (score 0):

You just trying to use method `getProvider()` from current object. `$this` is pointer current object of `MessageController` what extends `ContainerAware`. If these both classes (and their parents) do not has `getProvider()` method, throwing is an error.

I see you just imported `use FOS\MessageBundle\Provider\ProviderInterface;` instance. Reading the FOSMessageBundle documentation:

> Get the threads in the inbox of the authenticated user::

```
$provider = $container->get('fos_message.provider');
$threads = $provider->getInboxThreads();
```

Also you need to register provider in container earlier (read more on [Setting up FOSMessageBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSMessageBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/01-installation.md) and [Basic Usage of FOSMessageBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSMessageBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/02-basic-usage.md)).